# IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are v

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
def get_recommendations(title, cosine_sim=cosine_sim):
    # Get the index of the movie that matches the title
  

    # Get the pairwsie similarity scores of all movies with that movie
    sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[movies['name']]))

    # Sort the movies based on the similarity scores
    sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    # Get the scores of the 10 most similar movies
    sim_scores = sim_scores[1:11]

    # Get the movie indices
    movie_indices = [i[0] for i in sim_scores]

    # Return the top 10 most similar movies
    return df2['title'].iloc[movie_indices]
```

e

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: What line does the error occur on? How is `df2` defined? (Is it a numpy array or a pandas DataFrame?) How is `movies` defined? Is it a pandas DataFrame? How is `cosine_sim` defined?

Comment: i try to build movie recemandation system here df2 is my pandas dataset and movies is my selected columns dataset and cosine_sim is cosimilirity

Comment: Please show the code where you define these variables. Without that, we can't see what is wrong with your code. And tell us what line the error was reported on.

Comment: This wasn't your question, but: why are you ignoring `sim_scores[0]`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.